# Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

After trying to create a new scaffolded item - MVC controller with views using EF I get the following error:

```
Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions 
OnlineShop.Data.OnlineShopDbContext while attempting to activate 
OnlineShop.Data.OnlineShopDbContext
```

All I could find were problems regarding the registration of services, but I believe I did that correctly.

Program.cs

```c
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OnlineShop.Data;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<OnlineShopDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

OnlineShopDbContext.cs

```c
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using OnlineShop.Data.Entities;

namespace OnlineShop.Data
{
    public class OnlineShopDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public OnlineShopDbContext(DbContextOptions<OnlineShopDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder
                .Entity<Order>()
                .Property(order => order.OrderStatus)
                .HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<OrderStatus>());
        }
    }
}
```

OnlineShopDbContext.cs is in another project (OnlineShop.Data) than the Program.cs file. I have referenced the Data project into the main project, and the build order is Data, then main project. Wierdly, the code generation runs fine when OnlineShopDbContext.cs is in the same project as the Program.cs and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you please add full [mre]? It seems that you have two `OnlineShopDbContext`s defined in different namespaces (and projects) and  `builder.Services.AddDbContext<OnlineShopDbContext>` uses the different one compared to one being resolved.

Comment: I edited the question so you can see the references. Only one `OnlineShopDbContext` was defined in any moment of the app. I double checked and the `OnlineShopDbContext` used in `.AddDbContext<>` is correctly referenced from `OnlineShop.Data`